# Is there any reason to resteal larceny targets?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After retrieving larceny targets like the jeweled candlestick on missions for the Thieves Guild, they appear on a bookshelf in the Ragged Flagon.  I'm wondering if you're meant to steal them again after you've sold them to Delvin.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but there's really no point since you can't sell it back to Delvin again.

Comment: Well I'm Making a treasure cove and the candle stick showed up but I can't take it, must be a bug